# For two closed operators $A,B$, can we say that $P_i\uparrow 1$ and $(A-B)P_i =0$ implies $A-B$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, adjoint-operators

Let $A,B$ be two closed operators on a Hilbert space. Let $P_i$ be an increasing net of projections with $P_i\uparrow {\bf 1}$. If $(A-B)P_i =0$ for every $i$ (if necessary, we may assume that $AP_i,BP_i$ are bounded and self-adjoint for every $i$), do we have $A-B=0$?

Comment: I don't quite get your question; do you meant $A - B = 0$ or perhaps $A = B$?  I mean, what *about* $A - B$?  Cheers!

Comment: Ah, sorry. I meant A-B=0  @RobertLewis

Comment: Would you mind to give the definition of *closed operator*? Is it continuous?

Comment: they are just general closed operators. Sorry, I can not give a specific definition @C.Ding

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication is a separately continuous map in WOT, SOT and norm.

I would guess the same is true for any reasonable locally convex topology in B(H).

Comment: what topology do we have for closed operators?

Comment: I completely overlook that your operators are closed instead of bounded.